# Moodle: allow Restricted EMail Domains for manually created users?

Tags: authentication, moodle, administration

I use EMail based self registration on v4.3 of Moodle and only allow users from specific email domains to register.

However, we have some users that need a profile with a different domain (like 10 profiles or so) from big providers like gmail.com. We created these profiles manually, but when they try to login they get redirected to their user profile, so they have to update their mail.

Is it possible to disable this restriction for profiles of users I created manually? So, that once they are created manually they don't have to use an allowed email address in their profile.

If not possible maybe whitelist the whole email-address and not just the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Found out: there is an option in the authentification plugin settings > "verifychangedemail"